# Ansible with items loop inside my inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a task based on a shell command that needs to run on a local computer. As part of the command, I need to add the IP address on part of the groups I have in my inventory file

**Inventory file :**

```
[server1]
130.1.1.1
130.1.1.2

[server2]
130.1.1.3
130.1.1.4

[server3]
130.1.1.5
130.1.1.6
```

I need to run the following command from the local computer on the Ips that are part of the  Server 2 + 3 groups

```
ssh-copy-id user@<IP>
# <IP> should be 130.1.1.3 ,  130.1.1.4 , 130.1.1.5 , 130.1.1.6
```

**Playbook - were I'm missing the part of the ip**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
     - name: Generate ssh key for root user
       shell: "ssh-copy-id user@{{ item }}"
       run_once: True
       with_items:
           - server2 group
           - server3 group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- hosts: server1:server2
  gather_facts: no
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Push local root pub key for remote user
      shell: "ssh-copy-id user@{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Note that I kept your exact shell command which is actually a bad practice since there is a [dedicated ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html) to manage that. So this could be translated to something like.

```yaml
- hosts: server1:server2
  gather_facts: no
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Push local root pub key for remote user
      authorized_key:
        user: user
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```